# CSS link opened and used for the second time is not working or letting me change or add something in the CSS file

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, css

Yesterday I had the same problem with the previous CSS file when I used it for the second time. The problem that I was having is that I can't do any changes with the CSS to my PHP and HTML file when I used the CSS file for the specific HTML or PHP file. I did learn the basic CSS and how to link an external CSS file and that the external file is `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signcss.css">` (This is my CSS file that I'm currently using) I don't really know what kind of issue that I'm having, but I was having this kind of problem since the time that I was using the Bracket editor in which I thought it has some kind of problem in its system or something because that was the start of my problem with the CSS link not connecting to my HTML file and I'm now using sublime free and I still get the problem and the same goes for the notepad++. Please help me because I can't really find an answer, even on the internet and with this problem, it's gonna get hard for me in the future.

This is my PHP file and I'm pretty much attempting to make my own signup page.

```
<?php
    include('seasion.php');

    include('hFunction.php');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
        <title>register</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signcss.css">

        <?php include('bootstrap.php');?>  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

          <div class="container">

        <h1>Start here  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></h1><hr class="style">

              <div class="error"><?php echo $error; ?></div>

        <form method = "post">

            <div id="box">

                <h3>Reminder:</h3>

                <p>Once you have been signed up click here.<a href="../index.html"> Home</a></p>

                <p style="color:red;">Hello and welcome to login/sign up page. Reworking the sign up page. Doing stuff with the Database or re-learning the mysql database</p>

                <p style="color:red;">Reminder if you want to log out, you will need to come back to this page if you want to logout. </p>

                <p>If you're already signed up go to do the login page</p>
                <button href="hapibeelog-in.php">Login</button>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="name">First Name:</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">

                <label for="name">Last Name:</label>
                <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">

                <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address">

                <label for="phone-number">Phone number:</label>
                <input name="phone-number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone number">

                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"><br>

                <input type="checkbox" name="stayLoggedIn" value="1">

                <input type="hidden" name="signUp" value="1">

                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up!">

            </div>
         <div class="break"></div>
        </form><br><hr class="style">

          </div>

        <?php include('bscript.php');?>

    </body>
    <footer>
        <div class="footerL">
            <h5>Date:2/21/17</h5>

            <h3>Source:</h3>

            <ul>
                <li>https://www.udemy.com/the-web-developer-bootcamp/learn/v4/content</li>
                <li>www.w3schools.com</li>
                <li>www.getbootstrap.com</li>
                <li>www.css-tricks.com</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="footerR">
            <p>King st.</p>
        </div>

    </footer>
</html>
```

This is my CSS file and the file name is signcss.css

```
body{
}

hr.style {
    border: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
    margin: 10px;
}
#box{
    border:1px solid #a6a6a6;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    background-color: #d9d9d9;
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 350px;
    width: 320px;
    top:100px;
    right:100px;
    float:right;
}

input.form-control{
    width: 500px;
}

.break {
    clear: both;
}

footer{
    width: 75%;
    margin:10px auto;
}

.footerR{
    float:right;
}

.footerL{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: does not compute `I can't do any changes with the CSS to my PHP and HTML file when I used the CSS file for the specific HTML or PHP file`

Comment: Your title almost sounds like you're trying to explain a caching issue. Try doing CTRL+F5 or SHIFT+F5 in your browser, and see if the CSS updates. You can also add `?v1` to your link's `href`, like so: `href="signcss.css?v1"`, and increment this each time you make changes. If this *does* resolve your issue, the problem is that your browser is simply caching the CSS. Because it already fetched it once, it tries to save time on the next visit by just re-using the file it already has, so none of the updates will show. You can force it to re-download the CSS using the methods above.

Comment: Thank you so much! The ?v1 really worked. I did a little bit of changes to mines using CSS and it really does work. I need to learn something about the caching issue more.